# Can you call Objective-C methods from C/C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, realm

The Realm mobile database have Objective-C and Java bindings, suitable for iOS and Android respectively.

However I want to use Realm in Blackberry and Windows Phone and Realm has no C/C++ bindings yet.

My question is: can you link/call Objective-C library from C/C++, with Realm library to be used in Blackberry and Windows Phone in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not the lack of C/C++ bindings that's your problem, rather that Realm only runs on iOS and Android - there is no Realm for Blackberry and Windows Phone.

The source is public domain though (Apache 2 licence), so you could consider porting it yourself...